# Convergence of derivative of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a compactly supported Lipschitz function which has first partial derivatives at almost every point with respect to $\mu$, a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

> What can be said about the derivatives of the standard mollification $\partial_i (f*\eta_{\epsilon})$?

The convolution integral here is done with respect to the usual $N$ dimensional Lebesgue measure, and $i\in \{1,...,N\}$.

By using dominated convergence (thanks to the Lipschitz continuity of $f$) it follows that $\mu$ almost everywhere the following identity holds: $\partial_i (f*\eta_{\epsilon})=\partial_i f*\eta_{\epsilon}$.

I'm interested in seeing what happens for $\epsilon=1/n \rightarrow 0^+$.

Is it true that $\partial_i (f*\eta_{1/n})\rightarrow \partial_i f$ for $\mu$ almost every point? Is it true that $\partial_i (f*\eta_{1/n})$ is uniformly bounded ($\mu$ almost everywhere)?

I guess the second claim could be proved in this way: for $\mu$ almost every $x$ $\partial_i f$ exists, hence $|\partial_i (f*\eta_{1/n})(x)|=|\partial_i f*\eta_{\epsilon}(x)|\le||\partial_i f||_{\infty}\le L$, $L$ being the Lipschitz constant of $f$. This is because the standard mollifier has unitary mass.

How about the first claim? Is it true if $\mu$ is the $N-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure?

Comment: Just to clarify. Your first claim is that $\sup_n \| \partial_i (f \ast \eta_{1/n}) \|_\infty$ is finite and the second is that $\partial_i(f \ast \eta_{1/n})$ converge a.e. to $\partial_i f$, right?

Comment: You should explain a little bit more which generalization do you have in mind for the $N - 1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Comment: There are more issues with the question. For instance $\Omega$ and $\mu$ are barely used. You just need the null sets of $\mu$ and $\ast$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}^N$. Where does the question come from?